# Xamarin Essentials FileSystem can you save async

Tags: xamarin

Looking into Xamarin essentials and wondering what the purpose of FileSystem is.

I was looking for something that would load and save a file for me async out of the box.

It looks to me and may be I am not understanding the usage that the only thing that it gives you is a location where to save and load the file and there is no functionality to actually save it for you  eg "Old PCLStorage"

is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Xamarin Essentials File System *Helpers* are doing is providing access to two different directories within your app, `CacheDirectory` and `AppDataDirectory` and access to the read-only pre-bundled files within application so you do not have to write platform-based code for these locations and do your own DI (or use Forms' DI) to access them...

Once you have the `string`-based directory location, then you use the normal .Net(Std) file and directory I/O routines. Create/delete subdirectories, create/read/write/delete a file using the async (or not) functions from the .Net(Std) framework or a third-party framework/package. Your choice...

#### CacheDirectory

The cache directory is a read/write location and it implements access to the "native" platform cache location. On Android this is the Cache

```
var cacheDir = FileSystem.CacheDirectory;
```

#### AppDataDirectory

The app data directory is the "default" location for where regular files should be stored.

As the docs state:

> any files that are not user data file

FYI: This is *not* the place to be used for Sqlite databases and such if you are implementing/complying with platform dependent norms... Why Essentials did not include a database location is unknown to me when platforms like iOS and Android have APIs for them and formally documented locations... ;-/

#### Application bundled files (read-only)

`OpenAppPackageFileAsync` provides access (via a `Stream`) to read-only bundled files in your application (`AndroidAssets`, `BundleResource`, etc..)

```
using (var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("sushiLogo.png"))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var fileContents = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you for your very detailed answer I understand way more about the usage.in our app we have the need to store some documents files to the device and we are about to implement our own saveasync if you like in both iOS and Android.i was hoping to get rid of that kind of code and replace with xamarin essentials.but from what you are saying it’s still up to us to save and load a file.I noticed that you provided a readasync but not writeasync which is more of interest to me .so what they are giving us that I don’t need to write code in both iOS and Android but obtain a location and save

Comment: @developer9969 The `OpenAppPackageFileAsync` provides a read-only stream as it is returning pre-bundled files in your app. If you are writing to a cache/appdata location you could use, for example, a `StreamWriter` and its associated async (or not) Write-based methods: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx Of course you could also use binary based streams/writers, etc... which also have async-based methods.

Comment: this is the bit that I am struggling to grasp. So in my case I should write to the cache directory and read from there using file system and correct me if wrong this is the only way to write to a file that can be read by xamarin essentials correct?do I still need the iOS and Android implementation then thanks for your time

Comment: @developer9969 `file that can be read by xamarin essentials correct` Essentials is not reading/writing anything to the cache/appdata locations, it is just returning a string that contains the path. It is up to you to create/open a File from that location. And no you do not need to write any platform-dependent code for that, just normal (cross-platform) .Net framework code.

Comment: @SushiHangover: I suppose the _FileSystem.CacheDirectory_ is mapped to the _cache_ directory on the vs2017 device emulator. If this is correct, I would like to upload a zip file to it, as using the fileexplorer on the emulator and the button 'Push a file onto the device' does not copy any file to the cache directory (permission denied)

Comment: @xy The "cache" on Android is mapping inside your app's sandbox and thus is a private (non-world viewable) directory. If you are using a root-able android image you could do that, otherwise you would need to copy your zip file to a public one (like Download) and then programmatically within you app copy it to your app's internal cache dir.

Comment: So, changing the permissions of _cache_ to **a+rwx** (from a su shell) does not help?

Comment: .. and using _Download_ would be not so fine, as I would like to work with the Xamarin.Essentials FileSystem methods, which only offer 2 - without _Downloads_

Comment: @xy If you have access to it via a `su shell` (thus your image is rooted), you can `adb push` a file from your PC to that directory.

Comment: Misunderstanding: I executed the _adb shell_ command in the _Android ADB Command Prompt_ then _su_. Then,  using the _FileExplorer_'s  _Push a file onto the device_ does not work  :/

Comment: .. and within the su shell (within the emulator) there is no _adb_ command available, allthough the _cache_ directory is now visible from outside with **rwx** permissions - So its rather strange, that I am not allowed to copy file to there (with adb push)

Comment: @xy IF you have a "rooted" image|device you are free to do whatever you what to the filesystem, otherwise no, a "file explorer" app is not going to be able to access your app's private sandbox. You could copy those files to your app's "public" directory (`Context.ExternalCacheDir()`), you will need to write some native code and access it via a Dependency service (assuming you are using Forms/NetStd)

Comment: @xy If you need a code sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54127487/4984832

Comment: So, where should I save the sqlite database in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Hi, well I got the same question, where is the best place to save a sqlite database? when using xmarinforms ?