# Access the Android Special Folder Path by using Environment

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to save my logs to a folder which I can access with windows explorer. For example I want to create my log in the following path

This PC\Galaxy A5 (2017)\Phone\Android\data\MyApp\files

So I tried to use Environment variables... I get such as

/data/user/...

But here i cannot see the file what I created (using code I can access the path but I want to see in the explorer).

how I can create a path like above with code?

When I tried this code

```
var finalPath2 = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory
(Android.OS.Environment.DataDirectory.AbsolutePath);
```

> I get the path "/storage/emulated/0/data"

and

If i use the code

```
   var logDirectory =Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath
  (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),"logs");
```

I get the following path like:

> /data/user/0/MyApp/files/.config/logs

and

```
var logDirectory =Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath
  (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),"logs");
```

> "/data/user/0/IM.OneApp.Presentation.Android/files/logs"

but unfortunately I cannot access this folder by explorer....

This PC\Galaxy A5 (2017)\Phone\Android\data\MyApp\files

So how to find out this path in c# by using environments?

Update:

when I give the following path hardcoded, it creates the file where I want..

logDirectory = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MyApp/files/logs";

is there any environment to create this path? I can combine 2 environments and do some string processing in order to create this path. But maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: @SushiHangover, I prefer to save in our app folder.. I am updating my question

Comment: @SushiHangover the given path works (I've updated my question) I just need to create this path..

Comment: That is public storage (emulated) as it is outside your app's sandbox, not private sandboxed app storage. Anyone can access it, just like Music, Download, Movies, .... The entire Android filesystem security model would be broken if you had access to private app file storage (i.e. a rooted phone)

Comment: @SushiHangover, of course. I meant ot to save file to folders by sandbox. But as you see the path, its "more" private than "downloads" folder. I hope its clear now. Thank you for your replies by the way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the root of `GetExternalFilesDir`, just pass a null:

#### Example:

```
var externalAppPathNoSec = GetExternalFilesDir(string.Empty).Path;
```

Note: This is a `Context`-based instance method, you can access it via the Android application context, an Activity, etc... (see the link below to the Android Context docs)

> - Shared storage may not always be available, since removable media can be ejected by the user. Media state can be checked using Environment.getExternalStorageState(File).
> - There is no security enforced with these files. For example, any application holding Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE can write to these files.

re: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

Comment: exactly this is what I want.. I gave already the permission. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
string docFolder = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath
     (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "logs");
string libFolder = Path.Combine(docFolder, "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MyApp/files/logs");
if (!Directory.Exists(libFolder))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(libFolder);
}

string destinationDatabasePath = Path.Combine(libFolder, "temp.db3");

db.Backup( destinationDatabasePath, "main");
```