# Cant find sql lite database on device or emulator but can access through code

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Xamrin forms and I cant find the database created when I use this code it works fine during the applicaiton but I cant find it on the emulator is their anyway I can store it and access it from the downloads folder which is always accessable during testing.

Also is their even a way to use sdcard on the emualtor would be better solution as I am gong to be using a sd card to store the database on the phones anyway.

It needs to be using Xamrain forms code not Xamrin.Andriod

```
public async Task<Boolean> copydb()
{
        DatabasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "StockApp9.db");

        if (!File.Exists(DatabasePath))

        {

            using (var assetStream = await Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("StockApp9.db"))
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(DatabasePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                assetStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
        database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DatabasePath);

}
```

I am wanting to copy the database of the device so I can inspect it to ensure that the values are being saved correctly.

Comment: To store it in the public "Downloads" you will need Android specific code to initially request runtime permissions to read/write storage that is external to your app's sandbox and to obtain the actual download folder path. Alternatively you can store it in "GetExternalFilesDir" but that also requires Android specific code (i.e. via a dependency service)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126671/access-the-android-special-folder-path-by-using-environment/54127487#54127487 Or you can use a non-Google emulator image that provides root access so you can extract the file from the app's sandbox

Comment: @SushiHangover is their no way to have it done generic their bound to be whole point of xamrin forms

Comment: You are asking for something that is *currently* outside of the design of Xamarin.Forms and|or NetStd2. The required permission runtime user request is available via pre-written NetStd2 packages using platform specific code but Downloads access is not (there might be a 3rd-party package written but I am not aware of it). So Xamarin.Forms contains a basic dependency service implementation to address this need of accessing platform related features that are not covered in its basic implementation, it is a simple DI, but it works very well for the task you are asking about.

Comment: @SushiHangover yet it can access the device personal folder file seems a limiation if you ask me.

Comment: Things like "personal folder" are mapped within the Mono runtime and are within your app's filesystem sandbox, the public downloads is outside of that and not "currently" mapped, like it or not, that is the way is currently is. You can also post a feature request : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/wiki/Submitting-Bugs,-Feature-Requests,-and-Pull-Requests