# Cannot get access to data directory on Android emulator

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using Visual Studio and xamarin and I cannot get access to the data directory to retrieve my database for inspection I am saving the database in the following way to the device for write access.

I am using a standard stk 7 andriod phone which is not rooted and cant be rooted for my test device but during simulation i am using the android simulator with visual studio and xamarin

```
public async Task<Boolean> copydb()
{
    DatabasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), DatabaseName);
    string sdCardPath = @"/sdcard/" + DatabaseName;

    if (!File.Exists(DatabasePath))
    {
        using (var assetStream = await Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(DatabaseName))
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(DatabasePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            assetStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see below the path I am telling above is the personal folder even on the emulator i cannot navigate to the data directory using the andriod monitor.

[image]

I cant click into the data folder on the right hand side of the of monitor i can other directories just not data.

I am using xamarin forms and c#

```
public FuelStockDatabase()
{
    Task.Run(() => this.copydb()).Wait();

    dataTransfer = new FuelStockTakeDT();
    DatabaseName = "FuelStockApp31.db";
    DatabasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), DatabaseName);
}
```

Comment: Save/copy the DB to the app's "external data" dir (  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126671/access-the-android-special-folder-path-by-using-environment/54127487#54127487) and you will be able to `adb pull` the file from that location or use a rooted emulator image (i.e. ones that do not have Google apps installed)

Comment: @SushiHangover OK I get that but how do i access a property i created say external db path from my xaml in my forms app

Comment: @SushiHangover i ended up using xamrian settings for that

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-application-preferences-using-xamarin-essentials/

Answer (score 0):

You have to root the device maybe. I'm using Total Commander adb plugin extension and it works fine. You have to navigate to the root folder of the android tools folder, open a cmd there, and write "adb root" and press enter.

It should also work with your approach, go to the data folder and it will shows the content of the data folder.