# Can I create public/permanent files from Xamarin App?

Tags: c#, android, file, xamarin, mobile

I'm making an App where I need to create CSV files with data I need to load in a software in a Windows machine. I want to connect an Android Device via USB to a computer and get the file from there. Is there any way I can create a file that's visible for a computer?

From what I've found you can only create cache files and files only visible to the app (neither my PC or the File Manager on the phone can see them).

I thought about creating a service in the network and send the data to that and create the file in the server but that would add more failing points and of course is more work, besides sometimes the app could be running in parts where the Wifi doesn't get to it and would mean I would have to do a temporal file and somehow upload it when it connects back, so not practical at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126671/access-the-android-special-folder-path-by-using-environment/54127487#54127487

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can create files and folders on external storage of the android device, which is publicly accessible. [Refer to this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=macos).

Note: You need to get permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to write and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to read from device's external storage.

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution, I was kinda confused with External Storage, thought it meant like the SD storage. I managed to to create the file but it wasn't showing up on Windows Explorer. It seems that the Android doesn't refresh the file system on some conditions until you reset the device. I had to implement a method that forces a scan on the file and now it works like a charm