# Xamarin Android write to sd card to user accessible file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-external-storage

I'm able to write to and read from the SD Card using this location: "/data/user/0/ASSEMBLY-NAME/files"

This works fine for internal app use, but the file is not accessible to a user.

Is there ANY way to create a file on the sd card in Xamarin.Android where the user can see it?

Is there a magic location on the sd card where I can create a file where the file will be visible by a user?

This concept seems so simple I would think it would take minutes to solve, but I've been at this for hours.

****UPDATE SINCE ORIGINAL POST ...****

Using the path from

```
Paths.ExternalStorage
```

gives the correct path to use to create/write/append to a file accessible to the user

```
var path = Paths.ExternalStorage + "/";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + fileName, fileContents);
```

will write/create a file to the apps folder on the sd card

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path + fileName, "\nappending to file");
```

will append to that file if it exists, or create it if it doesn't exist

The path I was using before, the

```
"/data/user/0/ASSEMBLY-NAME/files"
```

writes to the same location, but the files are inaccessible to the user

The files accessible to the user have to be viewed using a file viewer like ES File Explorer, but they can be viewed.

I hope this is helpful to anyone struggling with this issue like I was

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126671/access-the-android-special-folder-path-by-using-environment/54127487#54127487

Comment: What does this "but the files are inaccessible to the user" mean? Do you mean you get the error like access denied? If yes, you need the permissions to access the external storage.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT by inaccessible I mean the user can't SEE the file.  Permissions are good.