# How to open sqlite db used by Android emulator on windows

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, android-emulator

So i downloaded DB Browser which is gui for viewing sqlite db. The question i have is when i debug my android emulator i have the following path to my db:

```
/data/user/0/com.HotelStash/files/.local/share/HotelStash.db3
```

The path is derived from following line of code:

```
 private static readonly string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "HotelStash.db3");
```

So if i wanted to be able to open this from db browser or view in windows explorer how would i do that?

Note: I am using visual studio emulator for android.

Comment: That file is within the app's sandbox and you can not browse it unless you are using a emulator image that is root-able (the Google API image or Play image are not, the System Image ones are). Otherwise you can programmatically copy the file to a public directory (create a button/system setting/etc to do it on-demand) or create the file in a non-secure directory like your app's non-secure external dir, strictly for debugging sessions of course: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54127487/4984832

Comment: Hi, it seems can not browse the file form app's sandbox in PC. You could use a remote online database, then all can visit it.

Answer (score 1):

First you can download the db file from Android Studio itself.

Go to device file explorer , and look for your application package name inside data folder
/data/data/{package_name}/databases/

You can save it to local folder and use any SQLite browser app to view the content.

There is another plugin available for Android Studio , with which you can browse your db content in same way.

http://www.idescout.com/download/

Comment: I am not using Android studio hence xamarin tag on this post. I am using visual studio on windows 10

Comment: Sorry I did not notice that. With visual studio I don't know.