# SQLITE Delete item does't delete for real

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-sqlite

I got a xamarin forms app, and  the problem is when I delete an item from a sqlite table, it looks like  all works, the item is deleted from the collection, the grids got updated, etc, but when I restart the app, the item is still there. its like the delete only works in memory but it never got saved   in the database.

my code is below

I create an instance called DB in  my App constructor

```
    public partial class App
    {
        static Database database;

        public static Database DB
        {
            get
            {
                if (database == null)
                {
                    string nombreBD = "MyDataBaseFile.db3";
                    string _databasePath = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, nombreBD);
                    database = new Database(_databasePath);
                }
                return database;
            }
        }
................
}
```

I'm  using sqlite with tables created from classes, like this

```
db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
db.CreateTableAsync<MyType>().Wait();
```

where MyType is a class like this

```
public class MyType
{   
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Idtable { get; set; }

        ......
}
```

I try to delete a row of the table like this:

```
var x = await App.DB.GetItemAsync<MyType>(obj.Idtable );
int regsDeleted = await App.DB.DeleteItemAsync<MyType>(x);
```

the GetItemsAsync  is basically:  `await db.FindAsync<T>(id);`

```
public async Task<T> GetItemAsync<T>(int id) where T : new()
    {
        try
        {
            return await db.FindAsync<T>(id);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw new System.Exception($"Error sqlLite {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

and the delete method is  this:

```
public async Task<int> DeleteItemAsync<T>(T item) where T : new()
{
    try
    {
        int regsDeleted=await db.DeleteAsync(item);
        db.GetConnection().Commit();
        return regsDeleted;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        throw new System.Exception($"Error sqlLite {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

like I said I got no errors and  all looks like worked, but when restart the app, the item still there!!
any Idea? something to add in the  connection maybe?  transactions?... any help will be great

thanks

**UPDATE** After a lot of test ***I realize the problem is not the delete***. The problem is that every time  I run the app from VS to my android device through USB cable, I don't know how or why the database get restored from some backup, that I don´t know when or where was done. Looks like Android have a backup and the "data" of my app and when a new version comes he just restore the data. I read somne that said the Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory should not be used to save databases, so the question is. where is th right place to save the SQLLite database.Any Idea? My app don't deployed an empty database, my app create  the database  in the first execution. Does anyone knows how to avoid that restauration of the folder? every time I run the app from VisualStudio ?

Comment: I've never used `Commit` with sqlite before, what happens if you remove that?  Are you sure that your app is not repopulating the data on startup?  What if you call GetItem immediately after the Delete, does it still return an object?

Comment: [Example here](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/SQLite/SQLiteAsyncConnection/DeleteAsync/php-sqliteasyncconnection-deleteasync-method-examples.html), remove the commit line and check the db connection is correct before deleting.

Comment: I've added the commit because without it , doesn't work either, the app don't populate at startup, and even if it was true, that data is no aviable in the server anymore. I've drop all the tables, close the app, but when I startup and all the data came back as magic. I cant find the dataBase.db3 in my device to delete it manually  in the windows file explorer,  Maybe the way I'created the db file?

Answer (score 0):

The `DeleteAsync` works without `Commit`. I make come changes for your code. It works on my side.

I add the `PrimaryKey` and `AutoIncrement` attributes to ensure that each Note instance in the SQLite.NET database will have a unique id provided by SQLite.NET.

```
 public class MyType
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Idtable { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

}
```

The code for the connect to the database, save the record, delete the row and get the all the items.

```
readonly string _databasePath = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "MyDataBaseFile.db3");

    SQLiteAsyncConnection database;
    public MyType myType { get; set; }
    int i = 0;

    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Connect_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(_databasePath);
        database.CreateTableAsync<MyType>().Wait();
    }

    async void Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myType = new MyType() { Text = "Hello" + i };
        if (myType.Idtable != 0)
        {
            // Update an existing note.
            await database.UpdateAsync(myType);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            // Save a new note.
            await database.InsertAsync(myType);
            i++;
        }

    }

    async void Delete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = await database.FindAsync<MyType>(myType.Idtable);
        int regsDeleted = await database.DeleteAsync(x);

    }

    async void Get_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = await database.Table<MyType>().ToListAsync();
         try
        {
            var s2 = await database.FindAsync<MyType>(myType.Idtable);
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note if i restart the app, there is no `myType.Idtable`. So i use the try catch to make my project run.

Add four items for the database and detele the last one.

[image]

After restart the app, the items:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code, well this is really strange, I Test de app  pressing F5 in VS and deploying to my samsung via USB, well every time I do that debug-deploy operation, the DB appears like magic, if I  run the deployed app without presing F5 in VS, just running from the device,... all works as espected :(    
So I guess the android did something like a backup and I dont know why every time VS deploys the app the android's device, the operating system restore the backup.  This is really strange!!

Comment: I read this "This is not the place to be used for Sqlite databases and such if you are implementing/complying with platform dependent norms" in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393561/xamarin-essentials-filesystem-can-you-save-async 
Talking about use "Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory"  as the place for the DB,... If this is not the right place, where is it? Because  in that location the dataBase gets hide, when you try to reach if from Windows Explorer via USB

Comment: As i know, when you save the database in  the path, it still works. Have you try to test on other device or emulator?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. Very annoying and couldn't figure it out. After reading this question I have just deleted the db3 file on the android device rerun my app and now it works. I suspect that during development and changing the structure of the class for the table something gets screwed up. Deleting the database db3 (or whatever, sqlite doesn't care) re-created the the tables completely.

So how do you get to the file? (For a Pixel 5 emulator)

I used Android Studio and the DeviceFileExplorer (View>ToolWindows)

But where is it. Well In my app I use

```
private readonly static string filename = "xxx.db3";
...
database = new Database.Database(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), filename));
```

and I (eventually) found this located in data>data>(my Application Id)>files

where my ApplicationID is something like uk.co.mydomainname.myappname

I just then deleted the file with a right click delete

(Note: I found sometimes you have to right click the files folder and synchronise to refresh the tree and see the db file)

Hope this helps.

PS I wish for me (.net maui) the documentation explained more clearly the paths and where things get located/placed!!