# File Writes in .NET Maui

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-maui

I am trying out .NET Maui for the first time and I am working on an offline app that just stores some information that will be displayed on cards. The point is to be completely offline as to not have to rely on internet or data speeds.

The issue I am having is I can't write to the file, but I can read from it. Looking at the [File System Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=windows) Documentation I figured it worked a similar way for writing to files.

```cs
static public async Task WriteTextFile(string filePath,string data)
{
    using Stream fileStream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filePath);
    using StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
    await writer.WriteAsync(data);    
}
```

I put this into a Static Utils class I created and when I put in a path (Ex: "CardInfo.json") which is stored in the Resources\Raw\ path and labeled as a MauiAsset.

Any idea on why I am getting the Stream not Writable Exception? I am running it on Windows at the moment, but I am assuming this will carry over into Android, etc. I thought maybe it had something to do with the stream not having write capability, but the OpenAppPAckageFileAsync doesn't have an overloaded method that could allow for me to set any additional properties.

If I need to make anything more clear in this let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin Essentials FileSystem can you save async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393561/xamarin-essentials-filesystem-can-you-save-async)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AppPackage` files are readonly.

You may want to use the `CacheDirectory` or the `AppDataDirectory`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  `AppDataDirectory` is the one I needed. I am sure if I read a little closer I would have realized that was read-only. Thanks!